# jQuery bxslider dynamic update not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I am having issues with dynamically updating content with bxslider. I am able to successfully load the content by entering the li items in HTML. When I attempt to append or replace the ul html with new li content from my database, it fails to reload the slider. Here is the important markups from my script. Is there any reason why I get no errors in the console.log and no images or slides?

```
var url = 'image/picture.jpg';
updateSlider('<li><img src=\''+url+'\'></li>');

var slider, sliderConfig = {
    pager: true,
    pagerType: 'short',
    auto: true,
    slideWidth: screen.width,
    onSliderLoad: function(){
    $('.bx-viewport').css({'height':'100% !important'});}}

$(function(){
    slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(sliderConfig);
});

function updateSlider(data){
   $('.bxslider').html(data);
   slider.reloadSlider(sliderConfig);
}
```

Comment: I have made on answer and just have make an edit. please call the `updateSlider('<li><img src=\''+url+'\'></li>'); ` only after you have the data after the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, means call the `updateSlider('<li><img src=\''+url+'\'></li>');` only after you are having data using any delayed function like as ajax. I have put on document ready but you need to run after successful ajax request:

```
var url = 'image/picture.jpg';

var slider, sliderConfig = {
    pager: true,
    pagerType: 'short',
    auto: true,
    slideWidth: screen.width,
    onSliderLoad: function () {
        $('.bx-viewport').css({'height': '100% !important'});
    }
}

function updateSlider(data) {
    $('.bxslider').html(data);
}

$(function () {
    slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(sliderConfig);

    //update slider on load or after any ajax call success
    updateSlider('<li><img src=\'' + url + '\'></li>');
});

$('document').on('click', 'a', function () {
    slider.reloadSlider(sliderConfig);
});
```

Comment: I moved the update to an onclick button event to ensure that the page was finished loading. I see the content is added to the bxslider UL and when I call the slider.reloadSlider(), I see the controls on the right and left but no images. Could this possibly be an issue with the CSS formatting the bxslider LI content?

Comment: I have update the code a little and it should work now. let me know

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, thank you for your suggestions.

The issue lies with the CSS. Once i reloaded the slider, the CSS was setting to 0 on the .bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport, .bxslider and .bxslider li elements. Once i reset them to the necessary heights it resolved my issue.

```
$(".bx-wrapper,.bx-viewport,.bxslider,.bxslider li").css("height",newHeight);
```